# Two class to the same class, one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I would like to bring the posts belonging to profiles or pages.

How can I relate to the same class other than two classes.

What do you recommend for an arrangement like?

please help me.

```
class Profile
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }


 class Page
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public ProfileOrPage MyProperty { get; set; }   //<<< My Problem Property
}

 public void GetProfilePost()
        {
            List<Post> postList = new List<Post>();

            postList.Add(new Post
            {
                ID = 1,
                new ProfileOrPage {     // My Problem Property
                 ID = 3
                }  
            });

            Profile p = new Profile();
            p.Posts = postList;


        }
```

Comment: Add also your Context. And whats mean "My Problem Property"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance.

```
class AbstractPage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
class Profile : AbstractPage{}
class Page : AbstractPage{}
class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public AbstractPage MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```